# Vespa application config best practices

Tags: vespa

What is the best way to dynamically provide configuration to a vespa application?

It seems that the only method that is talked about is baking configuration values into the application package but is there any way to provide configuration values outside of that? ie are there cli tools to update individual configuration values at runtime?

Are there any recommendations or best practices for managing configuration across different environments (ie production vs development) ? At Oath/VMG is configuration checked into source control or managed outside of that?

Answer (score 4):

Typically all configuration changes are made by deploying an updated application package. As you suggest, this is usually done by a CI/CD setup which builds and deploys the application package from a git repository whenever that changes.

This way it is easy to ensure changes have been reviewed (before merge), track all changes that have been made and roll them back if necessary. It is also easy to verify that the same changes which have been deployed and tested (preferably by automated tests) in a development / test environment are the ones that are deployed to production - because the same application package is deployed through each of those environments in order.

It is however also possible to update files in a deployed application package and create a new session from this, which may be useful if your application package has some huge resources. See https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/cloudconfig/deploy-rest-api-v2.html#use-case-modify

Comment: How do you handle sensitive information in configurations? Is there any way (besides adding custom code) to retrieve this information from secured storage or services?

Comment: We have custom code to get named "secrets" from a secrets manager.The security model for Vespa has previously been to run it in a "secure environment", but we are working a lot on improving that and making all cluster-internal communication secure (using TLS). On-disk encryption has been considered but is not yet available (but would be possible using e.g. fscrypt). For now, see https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/securing-your-vespa-installation.html